# Tracing via loop with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, loops, reference, trace

I currently have a data frame that looks like this

```
Seq<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)
Direction<-c("IN","IN", "OUT", "IN", "OUT", "IN", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "IN", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", 
             "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "IN", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT", "IN", "OUT", "OUT", "OUT")
Amount<-c(0, 3000, 566, 600, 550, 25500,5500, 515, 3500, 3000, 100500, 4000, 515, 25500, 50510, 1560, 5869.43, 4850, 
          15500, 2000, 1367, 3083.41, 3500, 2500, 3000, 3000, 950, 516, 5500, 1500, 3500, 1400)
df<-data.frame(Seq, Direction, Amount)

  Seq Direction    Amount
1    0        IN      0.00
2    1        IN   3000.00
3    2       OUT    566.00
4    3        IN    600.00
5    4       OUT    550.00
6    5        IN  25500.00
7    6       OUT   5500.00
8    7       OUT    515.00
9    8       OUT   3500.00
10   9       OUT   3000.00
11  10        IN 100500.00
12  11       OUT   4000.00
13  12       OUT    515.00
14  13       OUT  25500.00
15  14       OUT  50510.00
16  15       OUT   1560.00
17  16       OUT   5869.43
18  17       OUT   4850.00
19  18       OUT  15500.00
20  19       OUT   2000.00
21  20       OUT   1367.00
22  21       OUT   3083.41
23  22       OUT   3500.00
24  23       OUT   2500.00
25  24        IN   3000.00
26  25       OUT   3000.00
27  26       OUT    950.00
28  27       OUT    516.00
29  28        IN   5500.00
30  29       OUT   1500.00
31  30       OUT   3500.00
32  31       OUT   1400.00
```

I want to create a fourth column called REF. What REF does is can be divided into two ideas. In part, REF should select the earliest 'IN' in the Sequence and gives it the number 1. If an 'OUT' follows it is given the same number. When a new 'IN' occurs, it gives it 2, and the following 'OUT' gets 2, and so it continues. However, REF should also take note of how much is left when an an OUT follows an IN so that it trace when the amount coming 'IN' will be depleted - this is how some references can end up having multiple numbers such as 2,3,4 because it is not until then that they are depleted. For example, in the data frame below what is referenced as 5 is not depleted until row 19, where an outgoing depletes the 100500 from the previous inflow and then starts depleting 4 (which still has 12985 left as 25500-5500-515-3500-3000=12985), leading to a denotation of "4,5". Note, it is Last-in-First-Out in that it needs to deplete the most recent inflow first. For example it depletes (5) before (4) because 5 is more recent. That is why it goes 6 before 2,3,4 as well in row 26.

The df I should end up having should look like this:

```
  Seq Direction    Amount   REF
1    0        IN      0.00     1
2    1        IN   3000.00     2
3    2       OUT    566.00     2
4    3        IN    600.00     3
5    4       OUT    550.00     3
6    5        IN  25500.00     4
7    6       OUT   5500.00     4
8    7       OUT    515.00     4
9    8       OUT   3500.00     4
10   9       OUT   3000.00     4
11  10        IN 100500.00     5
12  11       OUT   4000.00     5
13  12       OUT    515.00     5
14  13       OUT  25500.00     5
15  14       OUT  50510.00     5
16  15       OUT   1560.00     5
17  16       OUT   5869.43     5
18  17       OUT   4850.00     5
19  18       OUT  15500.00   4;5
20  19       OUT   2000.00     4
21  20       OUT   1367.00     4
22  21       OUT   3083.41     4
23  22       OUT   3500.00     4
24  23       OUT   2500.00     4
25  24        IN   3000.00     6
26  25       OUT   3000.00     6
27  26       OUT    950.00 2;3;4
28  27       OUT    516.00     2
29  28        IN   5500.00     7
30  29       OUT   1500.00     7
31  30       OUT   3500.00     7
32  31       OUT   1400.00     7
```

I believe a loop with buckets would work, but not entirely sure how it should be set up properly. Any ideas?

Comment: In row 19, Ref switches from 5 to 4. But since 4 has 12_985 left and the remaining OUT values of REF 5 (including the part of 15_500) sum up to a value > 12_985, why doesn't it switch to 2;3;4?

Comment: It is Last-in-First-Out in that it needs to deplete the most recent inflow first (5), then second most recent (4). That is why it goes 6 before 2,3,4 as well in row 26

Comment: But (4) is depleted before (6) starts. So, using your LIFO-principle, it has to be (2;3;4) in line 22 (or 21? 23?).

Comment: 4 is not depleted before 6 if you look closely actually: When the outflow in row 24 occurs there is still some left of 4. Then an inflow of 3000 occurs, beginning 6, but 6 is then immediately depleted by an outflow worth 3000, after which 4 is depleted. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

### Partial solution

So I started to think about a way to solve this task but I didn't finish it properly.

First step, we transform your data

```r
df <- data.frame(Seq, Direction, Amount) %>% 
  mutate(Amount = ifelse(Direction == "OUT", -Amount, Amount),
         REF = cumsum(Direction=="IN"),
         control = cumsum(Amount)) %>% 
  group_by(REF) %>% 
  mutate(agg_Amount = cumsum(Amount),
         new_REF    = as.character(REF))
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 32 x 7
# Groups:   REF [7]
     Seq Direction  Amount   REF control agg_Amount new_REF
   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <int>   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  
 1     0 IN             0      1      0          0  1      
 2     1 IN          3000      2   3000       3000  2      
 3     2 OUT         -566      2   2434       2434  2      
 4     3 IN           600      3   3034        600  3      
 5     4 OUT         -550      3   2484         50  3      
 6     5 IN         25500      4  27984      25500  4      
 7     6 OUT        -5500      4  22484      20000  4      
 8     7 OUT         -515      4  21969      19485  4      
 9     8 OUT        -3500      4  18469      15985  4      
10     9 OUT        -3000      4  15469      12985  4      
11    10 IN        100500      5 115969     100500  5      
12    11 OUT        -4000      5 111969      96500  5      
13    12 OUT         -515      5 111454      95985  5      
14    13 OUT       -25500      5  85954      70485  5      
15    14 OUT       -50510      5  35444      19975  5      
16    15 OUT        -1560      5  33884      18415  5      
17    16 OUT        -5869.     5  28015.     12546. 5      
18    17 OUT        -4850      5  23165.      7696. 5      
19    18 OUT       -15500      5   7665.     -7804. 5      
20    19 OUT        -2000      5   5665.     -9804. 5      
21    20 OUT        -1367      5   4298.    -11171. 5      
22    21 OUT        -3083.     5   1214.    -14255. 5      
23    22 OUT        -3500      5  -2286.    -17755. 5      
24    23 OUT        -2500      5  -4786.    -20255. 5      
25    24 IN          3000      6  -1786.      3000  6      
26    25 OUT        -3000      6  -4786.         0  6      
27    26 OUT         -950      6  -5736.      -950  6      
28    27 OUT         -516      6  -6252.     -1466  6      
29    28 IN          5500      7   -752.      5500  7      
30    29 OUT        -1500      7  -2252.      4000  7      
31    30 OUT        -3500      7  -5752.       500  7      
32    31 OUT        -1400      7  -7152.      -900  7
```

I added a column `control` which sums up all values in `Amount`. Since `control` get negative after row 23, all your remaining `REF`s are depleted, so I don't think this task can't be completed.

Nevertheless here is a first approach, perhaps you can build up on this one:

```r
# vector for storing the remaining Amount per REF
bucket <- vector()

for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  pivot_ref <- df$REF[[i]]
  
  if (df$Direction[[i]] == "IN") {
# store the initial Amount in the bucket, bucket index = REF
    bucket[pivot_ref] <- coalesce(bucket[pivot_ref], 0) + df$Amount[[i]]
  } else if (coalesce(bucket[pivot_ref], 0) + df$Amount[[i]] >= 0) {
# if the bucket for the current REF won't be depleted, use this Amount
    bucket[pivot_ref] <- coalesce(bucket[pivot_ref], 0) + df$Amount[[i]]
  } else {
# the hard part
# empty the current bucket and proceed to the bucket with index REF - 1
    amount_remain <- coalesce(bucket[pivot_ref], 0) + df$Amount[[i]]
    
    bucket[pivot_ref] <- 0    
    
    # print(paste("Remaining amount: ", amount_remain))

    while (bucket[pivot_ref] + amount_remain < 0) {    

      pivot_ref <- as.integer(pivot_ref - 1)
# stop condition, if there is nothing left
      if (pivot_ref < 1) {
        # print("Last row:")
        # print(df[i,])
        stop("Bucket empty")
      }
      # print(paste0("pivot_ref ", pivot_ref))
      bucket[pivot_ref] <- bucket[pivot_ref] + amount_remain
      # print(paste0("bucket[pivot_ref] ", bucket[pivot_ref]))
      amount_remain <- coalesce(bucket[pivot_ref], 0) + amount_remain
      # print(paste0("amount_remain ", amount_remain))
      df$new_REF[[i]] <- paste(pivot_ref, df$REF[[i]], sep = ", ")
      # print(paste0("df$new_REF[[i]] ", df$new_REF[[i]]))

    }
  }
  
  print(bucket)
}
```

This code stops at row `22` returning

```r
# Groups:   REF [7]
     Seq Direction  Amount   REF control agg_Amount new_REF      
   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <int>   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>        
 1     0 IN             0      1      0          0  1            
 2     1 IN          3000      2   3000       3000  2            
 3     2 OUT         -566      2   2434       2434  2            
 4     3 IN           600      3   3034        600  3            
 5     4 OUT         -550      3   2484         50  3            
 6     5 IN         25500      4  27984      25500  4            
 7     6 OUT        -5500      4  22484      20000  4            
 8     7 OUT         -515      4  21969      19485  4            
 9     8 OUT        -3500      4  18469      15985  4            
10     9 OUT        -3000      4  15469      12985  4            
11    10 IN        100500      5 115969     100500  5            
12    11 OUT        -4000      5 111969      96500  5            
13    12 OUT         -515      5 111454      95985  5            
14    13 OUT       -25500      5  85954      70485  5            
15    14 OUT       -50510      5  35444      19975  5            
16    15 OUT        -1560      5  33884      18415  5            
17    16 OUT        -5869.     5  28015.     12546. 5            
18    17 OUT        -4850      5  23165.      7696. 5            
19    18 OUT       -15500      5   7665.     -7804. 4, 5         
20    19 OUT        -2000      5   5665.     -9804. 4, 5         
21    20 OUT        -1367      5   4298.    -11171. 4, 5         
22    21 OUT        -3083.     5   1214.    -14255. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
23    22 OUT        -3500      5  -2286.    -17755. 5            
24    23 OUT        -2500      5  -4786.    -20255. 5            
25    24 IN          3000      6  -1786.      3000  6            
26    25 OUT        -3000      6  -4786.         0  6            
27    26 OUT         -950      6  -5736.      -950  6            
28    27 OUT         -516      6  -6252.     -1466  6            
29    28 IN          5500      7   -752.      5500  7            
30    29 OUT        -1500      7  -2252.      4000  7            
31    30 OUT        -3500      7  -5752.       500  7            
32    31 OUT        -1400      7  -7152.      -900  7
```

A few things need to be done:

- What happens, if the bucket is empty (as in this example)? My code stops here.
- The first occurence of `4, 5` is correct, the next one has to be `4`. You need to find a nice solution for this.
- `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` actually has to be `1, 2, 3, 4`.

Comment: You are right. That is correct, it should be retracting 3 and 2 there. Do you have any idea how to write something (a loop?) that would produce REF based on this logic?

Comment: I'm thinking of it but the work is still in progress. I'm thinking of storing the final values per REF in a vector and using those values to create the REF. But I have to think about it a little bit longer.

Comment: @studentofdata1234 I actually did not finish this task, but I hope this partial solution helps you to preceed further.

Comment: Did you use your example data?